# couldn't import golang modules

Tags: arch-linux, golang

I have a problem with importing a module `github.com/lib/pq` in GoLang. I'm using Garuda Linux and I think Garuda is setting go environments differently than windows or Ubuntu.

I installed using pacman, not from the official site.

So, I checked my go environment variables `$GOROOT` and `$GOPATH` which was by default set by the Linux distro.

Then, I installed postgres driver using `go get -u github.com/lib/pq` as well as tried with `GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/lib/pq`. The installed got stored in the `pkg` folder rather than `src` folder.

After importing the package, I am getting this error:

```
database.go:6:2: no required module provides package github.com/lib/pq: working directory is not part of a module
```

I tried by setting `$GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin` but still the same error. Is it because of my system configuration or go environments, I couldn't figure it out yet.

So, any fix to the error?

Comment: Are you using `go.mod`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `go.mod` in the root level of working directory. Type

```
go.mod init
```

to activate the `go.mod`. After doing that, install the external modules.